# Global hotkeys with two modifiers

Tags: c#

I'm trying to register the global hotkeys 'CTRL + SHIFT + 1 - 3' in C# but when I add another modifier (shift) it doesn't work when I'm pressing the second and third one.

Code for registering the hotkeys:

```
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, (int)KeyModifier.Shift | (int)KeyModifier.Control, (int)Keys.D1);
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, (int)KeyModifier.Shift | (int)KeyModifier.Control, (int)Keys.D2);
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 2, (int)KeyModifier.Shift | (int)KeyModifier.Control, (int)Keys.D3);
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work any more". Does it not compile? Do you get an exception? Does nothing happen when you press the hotkey? Does the wrong thing happen when you press the hotkey?

Comment: Sorry I explained it wrong, I meant it works for the first one but the other two ones don't do anything, it compiles fine though

Comment: `RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key.` Are you sure no other process has a hotkey for those? What value is returned by the `RegisterHotKey` calls? What about using different ids?

Comment: Indeed another process has hotkeys for those. Was just too stupid to realise. Thanks though!

Comment: Watch out for installed shovelware, Intel's is particularly notorious.  And avoid the keypad, what keycode it generates depends on the state of the NumLock key and whether you use the Shift key.